# Shiny FileInput to database

Tags: r, database, shiny, rcurl, r-dbi

I am creating a shiny app where the user is required to upload data (CSV) that could be fairly large using shiny's FileInput. I then want to save this data to a remote database.

Now I was wondering what is the best way to import the data into the remote database in a secure manner?

- By doing a dbWriteTable the database server looks for the file in its
  own file system not the server where the shiny server is running.
- By first reading the data into R and then doing a dbWriteTable seems 
  very inefficient. It also causes the shiny app to hang until this process has 
  been completed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What database system are your targeting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like below, it depends on RODBC package. But you can modify it according to your needs.

```
sqlInsertBulk <- function(data, table, connString, chunksize = 1000)
{
  stopifnot(chunksize <= 1000)
  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(connString)
  nrow_initial<-sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("SELECT COUNT (1) FROM ",table)) 
  #If data includes Inf value, stop function.
  numericCols <- names(data)[sapply(data, is.numeric)]
  if (length(numericCols != 0)) {
    if(sum(unlist(data[,lapply(.SD, function(x) any(x == Inf)),.SDcols = numericCols]),na.rm=T)>0){
      stop("Data includes Inf value.")
    }
  }
  chunknumber <- ceiling(nrow(data)/chunksize)

  qstart <- paste("INSERT INTO ", table ," ( ",paste(colnames(data),collapse = ", "), " ) VALUES")

  for(chunki in 1:chunknumber)
  {
    chunkstart <- 1 + chunksize * ( chunki - 1 )
    chunkend <- min(nrow(data), chunki * chunksize )
    chunkdata <- data[chunkstart:chunkend]
    valuestring <- vector(mode="character", length=chunkend - chunkstart + 1 )
    for(i in 1:nrow(chunkdata)){
      valuestring[i] <- paste("(", paste(sapply(chunkdata[i], function(input){
        if(!class(input) %in% c("numeric", "integer")) {
          input<-paste0("'", input, "'")
        }
        if(is.na(input))
        {
          input<-"NULL"
        }
        return (input)
      }), collapse=", "), ")")
    }

    qend <- paste(valuestring, collapse = ", ")
    q <- paste(qstart, qend)
    print(paste("Chunk", chunki, "is in process."))
    up <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,q)
    if(length(up) > 0){
      stop(up)
    }
    print(paste("Chunk", chunki, "is uploaded."))
  }

  nrow_final <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("SELECT COUNT (1) FROM ",table))
  odbcClose(dbhandle)

  if(nrow_final-nrow_initial==nrow(data)) {
    print(paste("All ",nrow(data)," data is uploaded."))
    return(T)
  } else {
    print(paste0("Warning!!! Only ",nrow_final-nrow_initial, " out of ",nrow(data), " are uploaded." ))
    return(F)
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this implies that the data has to be in R first. I want to avoid reading the data to R and would like to directly import the data to the remote database.